# How to save data in User class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read data from db and save data in class of user. But this class has only UserId and UserName. I want to save another information.what should I do.
This is my code:

```
User user = new User();
user.UserId = (int)ddr["id"];
user.UserName = (string)ddr["name"];
```

Comment: Where is `User` defined?  Is this a built-in class or something you control?

Comment: Add new fields to `User` model that you wish to save

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: how to add new fields?

Comment: I want to save (for example) phone, but there isn't a field for that.

Comment: You need to do some reading on the ASP.NET Identity framework.

Comment: How can I reading on the ASP.NET Identity framework?

Comment: Simply add an extra field to your to your class `User` where you've defined it.

Comment: I don't define the class User . it is a built-in class.

Comment: @Maryam, Where the `Phone` field(for example) is stored?

Comment: the phone is a field in database . I want to read it , then add it to class User.

Comment: If you own the `User` class just add the members you need. If not, then maybe the best solution is inheritance through composition. That is: create a new class (something like `UserInfo`) and add a property of type `User` in the new class.

Comment: @Maryam `I don't define the class User . it is a built-in class.` then create your own class??

Comment: you can even override a built-in class. this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910108/how-to-extend-c-sharp-built-in-types-like-string
or, just create your own class and add the fields you wish to give.

Comment: ok. now how can I use the object of class (that I made it myself) in other pages of my site?

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance through composition example:

```
public class UserInfo
    {
        private User User { get; set; }

        public int UserId
        {
            get { return User.UserId; }
            set { User.UserId = value; }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return User.UserName; }
            set { User.UserName = value; }
        }

        public string Email { get; set; }



        public UserInfo()
        {
            User = new User();
        }
    }
```

So you can use the new `UserInfo` as `User`.

```
UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
user.UserId = (int)ddr["id"];
user.UserName = (string)ddr["name"];
user.Email = (string)ddr["email"];
```

Comment: ok. now how can I use the object of class in other pages of my site?

Comment: As you would use a `User` object.

Comment: :) . It's unknown in other pages. I can't write textbox1.text=user.Email.

Comment: @Maryam create an object on that page too `UserInfo user = new UserInfo();` and then you'll have the access `textbox1.text=user.Email`

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't help you from here. It's all about the design of your application. For sure there must be some changes so the new class can be used.

Comment: the UserInfo class is unknown in other pages. and if I write your code the Email hasn't the value that I given in previous page. It has a new value. Doesn't it?!

Comment: It is a bit confusing for me because I don't know if we are talking about MVC, Web Forms, a Layered application..... if you have controllers, repositories, ....  For start I would change in the UI (in just one page) the `User` with `UserInfo` and take it from there. I'm very sorry but I can't help you more behind a keyboard.