# I would like to add a string extension method. But where should I add that in my Xamarin Forms application so it's available everywhere?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Here's the method I would like to add:

```
private string S(int i){
  return i == 1 ? "": "s";
}
```

I would like it so I can use it in any part of the application. But where should I add this and how can I make it so it's accessible everywhere?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910108/how-to-extend-c-sharp-built-in-types-like-string)

Comment: It needs to be `public` and `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, in fact, would be an `int` extension method. It needs to be `static`; also, in order for it to be accessible everywhere, it needs to be `public`. Extension methods need to be defined in a `static class`, and they should contain the keyword `this` before the first argument, which would be indicating the type to extend. So the final approach would be:

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public static class Int32Extensions
    {
        public static string S(this int i)
        {
            return i == 1 ? "" : "s";
        }
    }
}
```

To use it somewhere else, you need to use the namespace in your subject code file

```
using YourNameSpace;
```

And simply call it

```
int i = 3;
string str = i.S(); //equals "s"
```

Answer (score 1):

The method that you are showing is not an extension method. An extension method would (for instance) be this:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static string S(this string text, int i)
    {
        return i == 1 ? "" : text;
    }
}
```

The method has to be static, must be in a static class, and the first parameter must have the keyword `this` before declaration.

Put the class into the base of your namespace, so that you will automatically be able to access it from anywhere without having to specify the namespace with `using`.