# C# Syntax beyond me, a beginner

Tags: c#

Okay, so still very new to C#, so sorry if this is obvious...

There is some code I can't follow that was created by someone who is much better at C#than I am.

We have a class, call it "CC", and it has a number of fields, one of which is "FORM_NBR".

So, in a nutshell:

```
public class CC
    {
    public CC();

    //Many, many fields...
    ...
    public long FORM_NBR { get; set; }
    ...
    }
```

At some point, an object is created...

```
CC c = new CC();
```

and then this line is called:

```
c.FORM_NBR = c.FORM_NBR.GetCheckDigit(' ');
```

Now, there is this function deep in the library we inherited:

```
public static short GetCheckDigit(this long nFormNbr, char chFormTypCd)
{
    short nCkDgt = 0;   // Default to 0

    switch (chFormTypCd)
    {
        //Many, many cases...
        ...

        default:
            nCkDgt = CalculateCheckDigit(nFormNbr);
            break;
    }

    return nCkDgt;
}
```

My question is this.  Being new-ish to C#, how is GetCheckDigit getting called from a long?  What is this syntax?

I don't even know how I would describe/google this!

Comment: GetCheckDigit is basically an extension to long type. You can see it at first parameter. "this long" which means this function can be run on long type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an `extension method`

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type. For client code written in C#, F# and Visual Basic, there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

There's a good example of this on this SO post:

[How to extend C# built-in types, like String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910108/how-to-extend-c-sharp-built-in-types-like-string)

Answer (score 1):

GetCheckDigit is an extension method on the type long

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods