# ScraperWiki/Python: filtering out records when property is false

Tags: python, twitter, scraperwiki

I'm using the following code on ScraperWiki to search Twitter for a specific hashtag.
It's working great and is picking out any postcode provided in the tweet (or returning *false* if none is available). This is achieved with the line `data['location'] = scraperwiki.geo.extract_gb_postcode(result['text'])`.
But I'm **only** interested in tweets which include postcode information (this is because they're going to be added to a Google Map at a later stage).
What would be the easiest way to do this? I'm relatively au fait with PHP, but Python's a completely new area for me.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Best wishes,
Martin

```
import scraperwiki
import simplejson
import urllib2

QUERY = 'enter_hashtag_here'
RESULTS_PER_PAGE = '100'
NUM_PAGES = 10

for page in range(1, NUM_PAGES+1):
    base_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%s&rpp=%s&page=%s' \
         % (urllib2.quote(QUERY), RESULTS_PER_PAGE, page)
    try:
        results_json = simplejson.loads(scraperwiki.scrape(base_url))
        for result in results_json['results']:
            #print result
            data = {}
            data['id'] = result['id']
            data['text'] = result['text']
            data['location'] = scraperwiki.geo.extract_gb_postcode(result['text'])
            data['from_user'] = result['from_user']
            data['created_at'] = result['created_at']
            print data['from_user'], data['text']
            scraperwiki.sqlite.save(["id"], data)
    except:
        print 'Oh dear, failed to scrape %s' % base_url
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want this? I tried on the free ScraperWiki test page and seems to do what you want. If you're looking for something more complicated, let me know.

```
import scraperwiki
import simplejson
import urllib2

QUERY = 'meetup'
RESULTS_PER_PAGE = '100'
NUM_PAGES = 10

for page in range(1, NUM_PAGES+1):
    base_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%s&rpp=%s&page=%s' \
         % (urllib2.quote(QUERY), RESULTS_PER_PAGE, page)
    try:
        results_json = simplejson.loads(scraperwiki.scrape(base_url))
        for result in results_json['results']:
            #print result
            data = {}
            data['id'] = result['id']
            data['text'] = result['text']
            data['location'] = scraperwiki.geo.extract_gb_postcode(result['text'])
            data['from_user'] = result['from_user']
            data['created_at'] = result['created_at']
            if data['location']:
                print data['location'], data['from_user']
                scraperwiki.sqlite.save(["id"], data)
    except:
        print 'Oh dear, failed to scrape %s' % base_url
        break
```

Outputs:

```
P93JX VSDC
FV36RL Bootstrappers
Ci76fP Eli_Regalado
UN56fn JasonPalmer1971
iQ3H6zR GNOTP
Qr04eB fcnewtech
sE79dW melindaveee
ud08GT MariaPanlilio
c9B8EE akibantech
ay26th Thepinkleash
```

I've refined it a bit so it's a bit picker than the scraperwiki check for extracting gb postcodes, which lets though quite a few false positives. Basically I took the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive), and added some negative lookbehind/lookahead to filter out a few more. It looks like the scraper wiki check does the regex without the negative lookbehind/lookahead. Hope that helps a bit.

```
import scraperwiki
import simplejson
import urllib2
import re

QUERY = 'sw4'
RESULTS_PER_PAGE = '100'
NUM_PAGES = 10

postcode_match = re.compile('(?<![0-9A-Z])([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {0,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)(?![0-9A-Z])', re.I)

for page in range(1, NUM_PAGES+1):
    base_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%s&rpp=%s&page=%s' \
         % (urllib2.quote(QUERY), RESULTS_PER_PAGE, page)
    try:
        results_json = simplejson.loads(scraperwiki.scrape(base_url))
        for result in results_json['results']:
            #print result
            data = {}
            data['id'] = result['id']
            data['text'] = result['text']
            data['location'] = scraperwiki.geo.extract_gb_postcode(result['text'])
            data['from_user'] = result['from_user']
            data['created_at'] = result['created_at']
            if data['location'] and postcode_match.search(data['text']):
                print data['location'], data['text']
                scraperwiki.sqlite.save(["id"], data)
    except:
        print 'Oh dear, failed to scrape %s' % base_url
        break
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply. Not quite... I'm looking to search for tweets containing a certain hashtag (let's say #food - I'm hungry!) but I'm only interested in those which contain a postcode. So tweets such as "Anyone know where to get some #food near SW4 0JA?" are what I'm after - whereas tweets such as "Anyone know where I can get some decent #food around here?!" would be discarded. Hope that explains it - and thanks again for your help!

Comment: Is that not what the above does? I'm only printing/saving tweets that have a postcode in. I only used SW4 as the hashtag so that I would get data quickly.

Comment: I've changed it so that it's looking for the #meetup instead, and priting just the hashcode and username. If that's not what you're after I'm unsure what you are after!

Comment: Hi Andrew - I'm sorry, I missed the extra code you'd added! That's great... thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for your help Andrew. Taking it a step further, I'd like to be able to extract the `media_url` attribute (see: (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities)) but that's not as easy as `data['media_url'] = result['media_url']`, as `media_url` is contained in an array. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward from that twitter doc, you already are getting the json response, just need to drill into it. Best to post a new question if you have difficulties as I'm at work and wont be able to play without for ages.