# Regex for UK postcode

Tags: regex

I have this regex that I want to use to parse a UK postcode, but it doesn't work when a postcode is entered without spaces.

`^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?) {1,2}([0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$`

What change(s) do I need to make to this regex so it'll work without spaces correctly?

If I supply `LS28NG` I would expect the regex to return two matches for `LS2` and `8NG`.

Comment: Hello, just wanted to check: you want the regex to match `LS28NG` or to split it up and match `LS2` and `8NG` separately?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript UK postcode regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081786/javascript-uk-postcode-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, at least for your example of `LS28NG`:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?) {0,2}([0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR ?0AA)$
```

I changed the repetitions after the space to 0-2 instead of 1-2, and made the space in `GIR 0AA` optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `\s{0,2}` and putting brackets around the first and second part of the expression:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?)\s{0,2}([0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```

For:

```
LS2 8NG
LS28NG
```

It will match:

```
LS2 and 8NG
LS2 and 8NG
```

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/lA3fP6).

Answer (score 0):

Just add an optional space `\s?` at the end of the first group:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?\s?){1,2}([0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```