# How to detect an address or a postal code in a variable

Tags: php

My questions sound may different but I am really looking for solution.

I have a variable in PHP, let's say `$check`, containing a string. It can be either an address or a postal code. Is there any rule we can apply here to check whether variable has postcode or address?

Edit: This website is for UK

Thanks

Comment: Can you define what the format of the postcode is?

Comment: Can we see some code on what you have done so far ???

Comment: i am building website for Uk.so post code will be all Uk postcode.@andrewsi

Comment: @shail - in that case, all you need to do is write a function to check if the string looks like a UK postcode. If it is, the string is a postcode. If it's not, then it's an address. A regular expression would work perfectly.

Comment: `/[a-z]\d[a-z]\s?\d[a-z]\d/i` for the post code?

Comment: @MarcB - almost. There can be one or two letters at the start; and the final part is a number followed by two letters.

Comment: /[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[a-z]?\s?\d[a-z]{2}/i should do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite detailed link: [here](http://stuff.nekhbet.ro/2006/09/14/how-to-validate-an-uk-united-kingdom-post-code.html)

```
function IsPostcode($postcode)
    {
    $postcode = strtoupper(str_replace(' ','',$postcode));
    if(preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2,3}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode) || preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode) || preg_match("/^GIR0[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode))
    return true;
    else
    return false;
    }
```

Use:

```
$e = "AB235RB";
if (IsPostcode($e))
print "Valid Post Code";
else
print "Invalid Post Code";
```

I have written a UK postcode validator based off this, so I know it works :)

Comment: You will also want to deal with spaces as most people format their postcode as "bh20 6dq" for instance

Comment: (Incorrect comment deleted, and +1 added for spotting those annoying London postcodes)

Answer (score 0):

#### New Answer

As Marc B pointed out, my initial answer will not work due to the alphanumeric quality of UK zipcodes.  In that case, I suggest [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to regex match the zipcode, or you could do a [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) on `$check` and look for the length of a zip code if you can be sure no addresses will ever be that length.

I'd recommend reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive) for a good discussion on the regex required.

#### Old Answer

If it is a simple zip code (i.e. not like 12345-1234), you could check with [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).  That is a bit of a hack, but it may suit your purposes.  Even if it is a complex zip, you could always use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the `-` and check `is_numeric`.  This is of course assuming the address has some character/string contents and is not fully numeric.

Comment: uk post codes are letter-number-letter number-letter-number, as are canadian ones.

Comment: uk postcodes are alphanumeric. lol if it was numeric, i have done that earlier :)

Comment: @MarcB - Alas, UK postcodes are nowhere near as organized as Canadian ones.