# Javascript UK Postcode Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, postal-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UK Postcode Regex (Comprehensive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive)

I have the following code for validating postcodes in javascript:

```
function valid_postcode(postcode) {
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var regex = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i;
    return regex.test(postcode);
}
```

Tests:

```
CF47 0HW - Passes - Correct
CF47 OHW - Passes - Incorrect
```

I have done a ton of research but can't seem to find the definitive regex for this common validation requirement. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I have used this tester: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and your provided example worked as expected. First one passed, second not.

Comment: @willemD'haeseleer I have already dismissed that script because in my opinion, it is unnecessarily large.

Comment: @jnovacho I'm getting 'No match' for both examples in Safari 6.

Answer (score 9):

Make your regex stricter by adding ^ and $. This should work:

```
function valid_postcode(postcode) {
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var regex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
    return regex.test(postcode);
}
```

Comment: This does not allow for numerous London postcodes, e.g. Downing Street is SW1A 2AA and Buckingham Palace is SW1A 1AA. Try: `const regex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{0,1} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You want a 'definitive regex' - given all the permutations of the UK postcodes, it needs to be therefore 'unnecessarily large'.  Here's one I've used in the past

```
"(GIR 0AA)|((([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0-9][0-9]?)|(([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][0-9][ABCDEFGHJKSTUW])|([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ][ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]{2})"
```

Notice I never just use A-Z, for instance, because in each part there are always certain letters excluded.

Comment: This is correct, but is also a bit of duplication. This is already answered in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive

Comment: Indeed, I'd posted my answer before I'd read the question you linked to in yours.  Suggest question is therefore a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first line of your function. By trimming the spaces out of the target string, you allow false positives.

CF47OHW will match [A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}

```
CF matches [A-Z]
4 matches [0-9]{1,2}
(blank) matches \s?
7 matches [0-9]
OH matches [A-Z]{2}
W gets discarded
```

So, as Paulgrav has stated, adding the start and end characters (^ and $) will fix it.

At that point, you can also remove the \s? bit from the middle of your regex.

However! Despite the bug being fixed, your regex is still not going to work how you'd like it to. You should look at the following rather good answer on this here site [UK Postcode Regex (Comprehensive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive)