# Changing this first name validation to also say miust be more than 2 characters but less than 12

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have some code to validate a registration form, but it's really basic.

How can I change both the fname and lname to be greater than 3 characters but less than 12?

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
//first name
var x=document.forms["registerForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

//last name
var x=document.forms["registerForm"]["lname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Last name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

 //email 
var x=document.forms["registerForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: add what about people with names shorter than 3 and longer than 12 ?

Comment: I don't care for such people lol.

Comment: honestly though, i need some boundaries. I cant imagine there are many people called Si Tu

Comment: but why any boundaries at all? there are millions of people with 2 letter first names. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: You should not redefine `x`, since it's already been defined in the same scope.

Comment: Li (Wade trans) is the 2nd most common Chinese surname

Comment: This is the official website for people with names of more than 2 letters but less than 12 (www.PeopleWithNamesMoreThan2CharactersButLessThan12.com) You didn't know the scope of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `length` property of a string.

```
var fname = document.forms['registerForm']['fname'].value,
    lname = document.forms['registerForm']['lname'].value;

if (fname.length <= 3 || fname.length >= 12) {
   alert('Your first name must be between 4 to 11 characters.');
}

if (lname.length <= 3 || lname.length >= 12) {
   alert('Your last name must be between 4 to 11 characters.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a serious response. It works. Do you also know how to ensure an accurate DOB is entered? (DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: Not as easy as it sounds if you want to check, say, if there were 29 days in February in a leap year, etc. But you can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194464/javascript-dd-mm-yyyy-date-check

Comment: Ah, i've just looked over it. Looks tricky! I'm guessing validating a postcode (british) is just as tricky?

Comment: Google is your best friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969461/javascript-uk-postcode-validation

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
if (x.length<3 || x.length>12)
  {
  alert("name length is not correct");
  return false;
  }
```