# javascript expressions names

Tags: javascript, expression

I am a complete beginner to javascript and I have several things I need to correct on a form in order for it to work.  I have to make sure it doesn't reject any valid names (names with accents, hyphens, names with spaces between them).  At the moment my regular expression is -

```
var alphabetic = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

if ((alphabetic.test(fname)== false) || (alphabetic.test(lname)== false))
{
    alertmsg = alertmsg + "Name should be in alphabets:" + "\n";
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful

Comment: So add accented letters, hyphens, spaces, etc. to your regex.

Comment: I don't want to limit a minimum or maximum amount of characters within reason

Comment: Adding those characters wouldn't affect the minimum or maximum size of the string.

Comment: is this the regex? var alphabetic = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

Comment: visit the [jslab regex generator](http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
var alphabetic = /^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñ-\s]+$/i
```

Comment: ok thank you everyone, so if wanted to have a space in the postcode also separating the two parts? var postcode = /^(A-Z){1,2}\d(A-Z\d)?\d(A-Z){2}$/

Comment: postal code from where ? http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx

Comment: This seems to do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive

Comment: I have only allowed for upper case letters in the postcodes with the above expression, which wasn't desirable either.

Comment: No problem, you can add /REGEX/i modifier to use case insensitive

Comment: If I needed to allow for a space in a UK telephone, how would I do that? var telephone = /^0\d{9,10}$/

Comment: this could help you http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp space is \s

Comment: thank you Philippe, one last question if you don't mind.  To validate a statement I have made sure that the checkboxes and quantities are consistent with each other but I haven't made sure that at least one product has been selected or a total quantity greater than zero is supplied.  How would I do this?

Comment: if (((document.form1.ch1.checked) && (summer2012 <=0)) 
|| ((document.form1.autumn.checked) && (autumn2012 <=0)) 
|| ((document.form1.winter.checked) && (winter2012 <=0)))
{ 
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please enter Quantity" +"\n"; 
}
else if (((!document.form1.summer.checked) && (summer2012 >0)) 
|| ((!document.form1.autumn.checked) && (autumn2012 >0)) 
|| ((!document.form1.winter.checked) && (winter2012 >0))) { 
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please choose Product" +"\n";
}

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need, your js script seems ok, perhaps you'll need to open another stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1):

As Philippe recommended, if you would like to accept languages/alphabets other than English, I would consider more carefully which letters to include. [a-zA-Z] does not seem to recognize letters other than strictly 'A' to 'Z' in my testing.