# Regex for range of UK postcodes

Tags: c#, regex, postal-code

I have UK postcodes stored in a database like this:

EC1-3

S40-45

NE99

So it's the first part of a postcode, followed by a range of numbers (or just one number if there's not a range). So for example, I need a regex that will match EC1-3 with an input of EC1V, but not with EC4R.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide more examples of what you expect it to match?

Comment: @devnull that's what is was thinking about. EC1-3 is the 1-3 part literal or a range of 1,2 or 3? be more specific please. Also, more test strings please...

Comment: How about this?<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive

Comment: Well now I feel silly. :P It's as simple as that? I think that ought to do it. I'll try it out and see. Thanks.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs, nice find man.

Comment: Thanks Traubenfuchs, but that seems to be for matching a full postcode, whereas I just need to match the first part, which isn't quite so complex. devnull's solution seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Tom I have a C# struct on GitHub that will allow you to match the first or whole of postcodes, complete with unit tests - https://github.com/ianfnelson/Postcode

Comment: Thanks Ian. That's a bit more than I need though. I'll keep it in mind if I do need it one day though!