# "regex.match is not a function" when called on a JavaScript rexex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the major part of a UK postcode. For example, the following are expected...

> M34EF -> M3
>
> M3 4EF -> M3

I already have the postcode (and just the postcode) in a JavaScript variable. Based on a [regex I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26493726/706346), I thought the following should work...

```js
var regex = /^[A-Z0-9]{3}([A-Z0-9](?=\s*[A-Z0-9]{3}|$))?/;
var major = regex.match(postcode);
```

...but this gives the error shown above.

What am I doing wrong? Or, is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.match` should be called on your `postcode` string.

```
postcode.match(regex)
```

It is `String.prototype` method. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Thanks for that. The reason I did it that way was because on the preceding lines (not shown as they were working), where I validated the postcode as a whole, I did exactly what I showed, although I was calling `text` rather than `match`. Anyway, works now, thanks