# Javascript Regular Expression Error Testing a Postcode

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use the postcode regular expression specified here: [UK Postcode Regex (Comprehensive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive) with javascript, but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm using:

```
var postcode = "^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y]))) {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$";
var aPCode = frm.PCode.value;
if (!(postcode.test(aPCode)))
{
  AnError += "Invalid Postcode.\n";
}
```

The error I'm getting is with the `if (!(postcode.test(aPCode)))` line.  IE7 (the browser where I have JavaScript errors enabled) reports back with the error "Object doesn't support this property or method.".  This implies that I cannot use the `.test` method on a string, but that's where it's supposed to be used, isn't it?  I can't seem to find the fault with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postcode` is a string, not a regular expression. Wrap it in forward slashes and remove the wrapping quotes to make it a regular expression:

```
var postcode = /^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y]))) {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$/;
```

[see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Or run the string version of the regular expression into the `RegExp` object to convert it:

```
var postcode = "^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y]))) {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$";
var postcode = new RegExp(postcode);
```