# Blanks in LIKE function to validate UK postcode?

Tags: sql, validation, ms-access-2010, sql-like

I'm trying to validate a UK post code field in MS Access using the `LIKE` function and I need to be able to allow the possibility that a character be `A-Z`, `0-9`, or simply not be present.

Some postcodes have 1 digit for the first section, others have 2.

So far I have the following:

```
Like "[A-Z][A-Z,0-9][A-Z,0-9][A-Z,0-9,][ ][0-9][A-Z,0-9][A-Z,0-9]"
```

However, the third and fourth characters may not even exist in a given post code, how can I handle this?

Comment: You need to use a regex not like. If you substitute one of the regexes from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive) into the code in PaulFrancis's answer, you will be most of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function which I have used in the past, not sure if it is the best. However I know it work(ed)s. So you might want to give it a try.

http://mikeperris.com/access/VBA-code-validate-UK-postcode.html

The Author of the code uses a **RegEx** patter to match the post code based on its length. This provides a major advantage of avoiding the use of LIKE.

Provides a simple **True**, if the postcode is valid  or **False**, if it is invalid.