# Struggling with SQL Where filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, [Customer], which has [postcode] and [totalValue] fields.

I need to design a query that returns the first two characters of all [postcode], and then a SUM of the [totalValue] for that particular postcode group (so one value each for NW, L1, etc.).

I have this code, which is running fine:

```
SELECT LEFT(postcode, 2), SUM(totalValue)
  FROM Customer
  GROUP BY LEFT(postcode, 2)
```

...however I have entries in [Customer] that don't contain a valid [postcode].

A valid UK postcode is always either one or two letters followed by a number (e.g. LE1, L12, etc.).

I would like to filter out all the incorrect/empty/Null [postcode] records into a separate record entry, but this is beyond my skillset.

Comment: What version of SQL server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
where postcode like '[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%'
```

You might also want to check the length and other characteristics, but this answers your specific question.

EDIT:

For a separate entry, use `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN postcode like '[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%'
             THEN LEFT(postcode, 2)
             ELSE 'Separate Entry'
        END) as PostCode2, SUM(totalValue)
FROM Customer
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN postcode like '[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%'
               THEN LEFT(postcode, 2)
               ELSE 'Separate Entry'
          END);
```

Comment: The OP indicated they would like to also display the invalid codes is a separate entry...  This just removes them.

Comment: Just thinking outside the box here but  a second query which doesn't aggreate the data since the postal could would be lost.... `where postcode **not** like '[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%'`

Comment: But it's possible to do it in a single query... just thinking outside the box.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro . . . Just didn't parse the whole sentence correctly.  It starts "I would like to filter out . . . ".

Comment: "I would like to filter out all the incorrect/empty/Null [postcode] records **into a separate record entry**, but this is beyond my skillset."

Comment: Mascaro is right, but in terms of just showing valid postcode entries this is working a treat thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions about valid postcodes is slightly out

> A valid UK postcode is always either one or two letters followed by a number (e.g. LE1, L12, etc.).

In its simplest terms the [valid formats for a UK Postcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom) are:

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| Format   |               Coverage                      | Example  |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| AA9A 9AA | WC postcode area; EC1–EC4, NW1W, SE1P, SW1  | EC1A 1BB |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| A9A 9AA  | E1W, N1C, N1P                               | W1A 0AX  |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| A9 9AA   | B, E, G, L, M, N, S, W                      | M1 1AE   |
| A99 9AA  |                                             | B33 8TH  |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| AA9 9AA  |    All other postcodes                      | CR2 6XH  |
| AA99 9AA |                                             | DN55 1PT |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Each of which you can define a pattern match for:

```
AA9A 9AA - [A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
A9A 9AA  - [A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
A9 9AA   - [A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
A99 9AA  - [A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
AA9 9AA  - [A-Z][A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
AA99 9AA - [A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
```

For something as re-usable as this, I think it is worth storing, so I would create a table for it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SimplePostCodeValidation
(
    PostCode VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    Pattern VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT dbo.SimplePostCodeValidation (PostCode, Pattern)
VALUES
    ('AA9A 9AA', '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('A9A 9AA', '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('A9 9AA', '[A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('A99 9AA', '[A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('AA9 9AA', '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('AA99 9AA', '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    -- REPEAT THE POSTCODES WITHOUT SPACES
    ('AA9A9AA', '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('A9A9AA', '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('A99AA', '[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('A999AA', '[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('AA99AA', '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'),
    ('AA999AA', '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]');
```

Now you can easily validate your postcodes:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Postcode VARCHAR(8));
INSERT @T (PostCode)
SELECT PostCode
FROM dbo.SimplePostCodeValidation
UNION ALL
SELECT  PostCode
FROM    (VALUES ('123456'), (''), ('TEST')) t (PostCode);

SELECT  t.PostCode, IsValid = CASE WHEN pc.PostCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM    @T AS t
        LEFT JOIN SimplePostCodeValidation AS pc
            ON t.PostCode LIKE pc.Pattern;
```

Which returns:

```
PostCode    IsValid
----------------------
AA9A 9AA    1
A9A 9AA     1
A9 9AA      1
A99 9AA     1
AA9 9AA     1
AA99 9AA    1
123456      0
            0
TEST        0
```

To apply this to your situation you would use:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN pc.PostCode IS NULL THEN 'Invalid' ELSE LEFT(c.postcode, 2) END, 
        TotalValue = SUM(totalValue)
FROM    Customer AS c
        LEFT JOIN SimplePostCodeValidation AS pc
            ON t.PostCode LIKE pc.Pattern;
GROUP BY CASE WHEN pc.PostCode IS NULL THEN 'Invalid' ELSE LEFT(c.postcode, 2) END;
```

If you want to get more complicated, there are actually further limitations to what is a valid postcode, e.g. if it is the pattern `A9 9AA` then the first letter can only be one of (B, E, G, L, M, N, S, W). The guidelines set out on wikipedia state:

- Areas with only single-digit districts: BR, FY, HA, HD, HG, HR, HS, HX, JE, LD, SM, SR, WC, WN, ZE (although WC is always subdivided by a further letter, e.g. WC1A).
- Areas with only double-digit districts: AB, LL, SO.
- Areas with a district '0' (zero): BL, BS, CM, CR, FY, HA, PR, SL, SS (BS is the only area to have both a district 0 and a district 10).
- The following central London single-digit districts have been further divided by inserting a letter after the digit and before the space: EC1–EC4 (but not EC50), SW1, W1, WC1, WC2, and part of E1 (E1W), N1 (N1C and N1P), NW1 (NW1W) and SE1 (SE1P).
- The letters QVX are not used in the first position.
- The letters IJZ are not used in the second position.
- The only letters to appear in the third position are ABCDEFGHJKPSTUW when the structure starts with A9A.
- The only letters to appear in the fourth position are ABEHMNPRVWXY when the structure starts with AA9A.
- The final two letters do not use the letters CIKMOV, so as not to resemble digits or each other when hand-written.
- Post code sectors are one of ten digits: 0 to 9 with 0 only used once 9 has been used in a post town, save for Croydon and Newport (see above).

Since SQL Server does not support full regex it gets a bit more complicated to account for all these caveats. If you really wanted fool proof validation I would be inclined to use the regex from [answers this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164979/1048425), and use a CLR function to validate the postcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. All incorrect (or NULL) postcodes will be accumulated in '--' entry:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN postcode like '[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%'
    THEN LEFT(postcode, 2)
    ELSE '--'
  END, 
  SUM(totalValue)
FROM Customer
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN postcode like '[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%'
    THEN LEFT(postcode, 2)
    ELSE '--'
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT CASE WHEN postcode LIKE('[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]%')
                         THEN LEFT(postcode,2) ELSE 'Invalid' END AS PostCode
                   ,totalValue
             FROM Customer)
SELECT PostCode, SUM(totalValue) as totalValue
FROM CTE
GROUP BY PostCode
```

Uses a `CTE` to gather the data.  Invalid postcodes will be grouped into 'Invalid'.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
SELECT LEFT(postcode, 2), SUM(totalValue)
  FROM Customer
WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(postcode, 1))<> 1
GROUP BY LEFT(postcode, 2)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

This is the select:

```
SELECT LEFT(postcode, 2), SUM(totalValue)
FROM Customer
WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL AND postcode != '' AND dbo.fn_isValid(postcode) = 1
GROUP BY LEFT(postcode, 2)
UNION
SELECT 'NULL', SUM(totalValue)
FROM Customer
WHERE postcode IS NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(postcode, 2)
UNION 
SELECT 'EMPTY', SUM(totalValue)
FROM Customer
WHERE postcode = ''
GROUP BY LEFT(postcode, 2)
UNION
SELECT 'WRONG', SUM(totalValue)
FROM Customer
WHERE dbo.fn_isValid(postcode) = 0
GROUP BY LEFT(postcode, 2)
```

Then you need the evaluation function, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_IsValid]
    (
    @Code nchar(32)
    )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Status bit

SET @Status = -- Your validation logic
--be aware of empty and null values

RETURN @Status
END
```

Comment: Scalar functions are horrible for performance. There really isn't any reason to use one here.

Comment: You're right I edited some code I had for other purposes in my current project and didn't really check for another solution, my fault