# Uk Postcode Ng-Pattern Angularjs Not working

Tags: angularjs, regex, postal-code, ng-pattern

I have tried multiple reg ex expressions on my `ng-pattern` in angular js, I have test this pattern on an online regex tester and it works fine

`/^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][‌​0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) ?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$/i`

I only want the postcode to contain uppercase characters and the postcode requires a space.

But when I use it inside my app, it allows for lowercase and a space. Which I do not want. Any ideas guys.

Comment: Are you sure of your requirements? If you need uppercase letters only, why use `[Gg]` instead of `G` and why specify `/i` modifier? There are spaces in your pattern, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive

Comment: I need uppercase and a space for the post code, ive tried several and i cant seem to get any work

Comment: @user3355603: First reason as Wiktor pointed out, because you are specifying `i`. It's for case insensitive. Even if you allow only ucpper case it will match lower case. And second your reges itself is matching lower case letters.