# Excel - Does Cell contain one of many specific 2 letter sequences

Tags: excel

I work in a territory based position, and so I need to separate a list based on UK postcodes

I have a list of my own postcodes and need a formula to check each postcode against my list and give me a true or false value, I have tried 2 variations of 'cell contains one of many things' but I end up with false positives and I am not sure why. The second value should be False.

[image: Formula Trouble]

Many Thanks!

Comment: how about IFERROR(MATCH(D3,$B$3:$B$60,0)>0,FALSE)?

Comment: If using VBA is an option, a more robust solution would be to implement a [regex-based postcode validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive).

Comment: @Rosetta that appears on first try to work beautifully, thank you!

Comment: @jsheeran if these lists become a regular occurrence I will probably look to do just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IFERROR(MATCH(D3,$B$3:$B$60,0)>0,FALSE)
```

`MATCH()>0` will generate a TRUE if a match found, but generate an error if no match is found, so `IFERROR()` comes in handily to translate the error to FALSE.