# Regular expression for UK postcode also matches UUID

Tags: java, regex

I am having problems with the following UK Postcode regex

```
([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})
```

It works for UK postcodes as intended e.g.

```
AB11AB
```

However, it also seems to match UUIDs as well e.g.

```
c25d4f64-2336-4a5d-b94c-14dc12xxxa58
```

Is there anyway to ignore UUIDs from the regular expression ?

Please find example here

https://regex101.com/r/dI6gD9/19

Comment: Thanks that is where I got the UK postcode regex from but it also seems to match UUIDs and I would like to ignore these if possible

Comment: That regex is overcomplicated for no reason.

Comment: As far as I can tell this whole mess reduces to just `GIR ?0AA|[A-Z][A-HJ-Y]?[0-9][A-Z0-9]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}` (assuming the `i` flag is set to make the match case insensitive). Technically the first ` ?` (optional space) is just ` ` (required space) and the second ` ?` is `\s?` (optional whitespace character) in the original regex, but I don't see why they should be treated differently.

Comment: Its taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/regex-for-matching-uk-postcodes

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51885364/1848654), which comes to the same result as my comment.

Comment: It's just not worth validating UK postcodes, what possible benefit does it give you? Put a maximum length of 8 chars and let people type what they want.

Comment: It's not for validation it's to mask log messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

Maybe, we would just add start and end anchors and fail the UUIDs, and change the capturing groups to non, if that'd be OK:

```
^(?:[Gg][Ii][Rr]\s+0[Aa]{2})|(?:(?:([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(?:(?:[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|(?:[A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s*[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

---

The expression can be most likely simplified (e.g., non-capturing groups), I have also added extra spaces, just in case.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/Zuo5Iv/1)

---

#### Option 2

Another option would be to add word boundaries, then it would become almost improbable that it would match a UUID in our data, that I'm guessing, and we can also add an `i` flag:

```
(?i)(?:\bgir\b\s+\b0a{2}\b)|\b(?:[a-z][0-9]{1,2}|[a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]{1,2}|[a-z][0-9][a-z]|[a-z][a-hj-y][0-9][a-z]?)\s*[0-9][a-z]{2}\b
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/bKbGXS/1)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?:[Gg][Ii][Rr]\\s+0[Aa]{2})|(?:(?:([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(?:(?:[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|(?:[A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\\s*[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$";
final String string = "c25d4f64-2336-4a5d-b94c-14dc12xxxa58\n"
     + "AB11AB";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Zuo5Iv/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Zuo5Iv/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: All those `(?: )` groups (except for the outermost one) are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct regex, that is issued by the UK government.

Below i added examples of how to use it:

**Match full string:**

When matching to a full string don't use the `global` flag, because then it will find the occurrences *within* a string, rather than testing a string to fully match the regex.

So don't use the `global` and `multi-line` flags

Notice the `gm` part in

```regex
/your_regex/gm
```

Try it in this [example](https://regex101.com/r/o8Esxo/2) on regex101.com, where I have already disabled the global and multi-line flag for you.

**Match in log file:**

For log files, add the `word` identifier around your regex

Notice the `\b` parts in

```regex
/\byour_regex\b/gm
```

Try it in this [example](https://regex101.com/r/o8Esxo/4) which shows this behaviour in an example log file.

Comment: That seems to work in the editor but what would the regex look like  ^/my_regex/$  ?. I am actually trying to get this working using java, so I need the full regex string

Comment: @mh377 What are you matching against? A whole file or multi-line string from which you want to extract matching lines, or are you trying to validate a single string?

Comment: The regex is used to mask postcodes in a log file. It is also masking UUIDs which I dont want it to do

Comment: @mh377 That's not what I asked. What is in the string you're matching against? If you don't know, at least post your code so we can check.

Comment: @mh377 I have updated my answer to account for logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, you just need to match it with the start and end of the string. Just append a `^` to the start and a `$` to the end of the pattern.

```
^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

https://regex101.com/r/jwLqLx/1