# How do I make use of postcode regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, postal-code

I'm trying to validate a UK postcode. How do I make use of the chosen answer in the following question via PHP?

[RegEx for matching UK Postcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/regex-for-matching-uk-postcodes)

```
 [Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A- 
    Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}
```

Comment: Just use it in the appropriate function. What is your issue?

Comment: You haven't copied the whole regex in the answer, it starts and ends with `(` and `)`, using that with e.g. `preg_match()` works just fine.

Comment: I have tried the following and I get an error: preg_replace('([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})', $_POST['postcode'] ,$_POST['postcode']);

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '|'

Comment: You need to use / as a delimiter inside the single quotes and outside the regular expression. For example `preg_replace('/([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})/', 'replacement' , $_POST['postcode']);`