# Formatting UK Postcodes in R

Tags: r, string, vector, format, postal-code

I am trying to format UK postcodes that come in as a vector of different input in R.

For example, I have the following postcodes:

```
postcodes<-c("IV41 8PW","IV408BU","kY11..4hJ","KY1.1UU","KY4    9RW","G32-7EJ")
```

How do I write a generic code that would convert entries of the above vector into:

```
c("IV41 8PW","IV40 8BU","KY11 4HJ","KY1 1UU","KY4 9RW","G32 7EJ")
```

That is the first part of the postcode is separated from the second part of the postcode by one space and all letters are capitals.

EDIT: the second part of the postcode is always the 3 last characters (combination of a number followed by letters)

Comment: In general it seems to be non-trivial, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/regex-for-matching-uk-postcodes/51885364#51885364) may be useful

Comment: @RonakShah - the second part is always 3 characters. So one can assume that 3 last numbers and letters form the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't come up with a smart regex solution so here is a split-apply-combine approach.

```
sapply(strsplit(sub('^(.*?)(...)$', '\\1:\\2', postcodes), ':', fixed = TRUE), function(x) {
  paste0(toupper(trimws(x, whitespace = '[.\\s-]')), collapse = ' ')
})

#[1] "IV41 8PW" "IV40 8BU" "KY11 4HJ" "KY1 1UU"  "KY4 9RW"  "G32 7EJ"
```

The logic here is that we insert a `:` (or any character that is not in the data) in the string between the 1st and 2nd part. Split the string on `:`, remove unnecessary characters, get it in upper case and combine it in one string.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Could I also ask you - how do I adjust the code to include formatting of postcodes that have a space before the first element, i.e. how do I make " G48 1PG" into "G48 1PG" within your solution?

Comment: `trimws(postcodes)` should remove those spaces.

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

1. Convert to uppercase
2. extract the alphanumeric characters
3. Paste back together with a space before the last three characters

The code would then be:

```
library(stringr)

postcodes<-c("IV41 8PW","IV408BU","kY11..4hJ","KY1.1UU","KY4    9RW","G32-7EJ")

postcodes <- str_to_upper(postcodes)
sapply(str_extract_all(postcodes, "[:alnum:]"), function(x)paste(paste0(head(x,-3), collapse = ""), paste0(tail(x,3), collapse = "")))
# [1] "IV41 8PW" "IV40 8BU" "KY11 4HJ" "KY1 1UU"  "KY4 9RW"  "G32 7EJ"
```

Comment: The `head/tail` construct is really good, especially `head(x, -3)`, and the `'[:alnum:]'` handles fringe cases of leading space as asked below.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove everything what is not a word caracter `\\W` (or `[^[:alnum:]_]`) and then insert a space before the last 3 characters with `(.{3})$` and  `\\1`.

```
sub("(.{3})$", " \\1", toupper(gsub("\\W+", "", postcodes)))
#sub("(...)$", " \\1", toupper(gsub("\\W+", "", postcodes))) #Alternative
#sub("(?=.{3}$)", " ", toupper(gsub("\\W+", "", postcodes)), perl=TRUE) #Alternative
#[1] "IV41 8PW" "IV40 8BU" "KY11 4HJ" "KY1 1UU"  "KY4 9RW"  "G32 7EJ"
```

Comment: this is the best solution (+1).

Answer (score 1):

```
# Option 1 using regex: 
res1 <- gsub(
  "(\\w+)(\\d[[:upper:]]\\w+$)", 
  "\\1 \\2",
  gsub(
    "\\W+",
    " ",
    postcodes
  )
)

# Option 2 using substrings:
res2 <- vapply(
  trimws(
    gsub(
      "\\W+",
      " ",
      postcodes
    )
  ),
  function(ir){
    paste(
      trimws(
        substr(
          ir, 
          1,
          nchar(ir) -3
        )
      ),
      substr(
        ir, 
        nchar(ir) -2,
        nchar(ir)
      )
    )
  },
  character(1),
  USE.NAMES = FALSE
)
```